# rounded corners, 1 corner remains defiantly pointy

Tags: html, css

This is a well healed topic but I can't find anything relating to my exact issue. And I have checked a lot! 
So my issue is, I am using rounded corners with no issue on one of my divs, I then copied the css over to my second div, which sits below the first. The top div has lovely rounded corners, yet the div that sits below has a pointy corner in the the top left. From what I've read and how the border-radius attribute works I didn't think this is possible. It does the same thing across firefox, chrome and IE. 
Here is a link to the css and html. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDFoe

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/854d00138368832cf142
I added the code to codepen and it works fine, however in all browsers still having the pointy corner issue. 
Any help would be great. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isolate the part of the code you're having an issue with.

Comment: #bubble1 {
 position:relative;
 top: -50px;
 width: 1013px; 
 height: 2500px; 
 background: #FFFFFF; 
 position: relative; 
 border-radius: 10px; 
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 
}

Comment: @Bee instead of adding respective code in comments, please update your question and add it there.

Comment: sorry pretty new to stack, will do so next time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is due to the image you have in the corner. Unfortunately, you have not provided a working link to the image in the Codepen example but if you comment it out

```
  <!--
  <img src="../../titles/the barn (Copy).jpg" alt="The Barn">
   -->
```

You can see that the border-radius is, in fact, being applied properly.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gicbK)

Does the image have a white background? Perhaps you could you move it with a little margin

Comment: Yes the images does have a white background. And your solution fixes the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one solution for cross-browser border-radius

```
.my-block {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* IE border-radius */
}
```